# ng build --prod UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: angular

Angular 4.3  I get the following error when trying to ng build --prod

```
94% asset optimization(node:7184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (i)
```

I have no idea where this issue stems from as thats the only error I can find.

Comment: Node version up to date? latest version is recommended (8.5)

Comment: yes node is updated

Answer (score 3):

Revert the angular CLI version 1.3.2 until this bug gets fixed:

`npm install @angular/cli@1.3.2` (add `-g` if you are using a global package)

You should be able to build now :).

Answer (score 2):

Same here :(

In my case the problem occurs in combination with popper.js as stated here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7725

EDIT: I found a solution:
Instead of using this one in the Angular-CLI-Configuration (.angular-cli.json):

```
"scripts": [
  ...
  "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
  ...
],
```

I used that one (i changed the library to the /dist/**umd** one):

```
"scripts": [
 ...
 "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
 ...
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue for an Angular 5 project, when running `ng build --prod` for ng version 1.5.2

```
94% asset optimization(node:26226) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (Commented)
```

I've tracked the problem to the include of a particular script via the `.angular-cli.json`, I have this :

```
"scripts": [
    "../libs/autobahn-js-built-17.5.2/autobahn.js"
],
```

... and further, I suspect the error happens during the minification stage (when uglifyjs would be invoked).

I can't seem to find any way to get further logging / diagnostics from ng , (I tried --verbose but just gives mainly timing stats, rather information on what sub programs are being invoked etc) ... will continue digging, suspicion is incompatibility between uglifyjs and the external javascript.

Answer (score 0):

npm install @angular/cli@1.3.2 ( @maximedupre answer )
Also need to have one more step before installing the above command is to open vs code in administrator mode